# Assign serial No based on column value in excel

Tags: excel

I have a few millions of data carrying city name. Now I want to assign serial no based on city names separately. I have almost 500+ cities. You can clearly understand by the following images. I have the city name as image 1. I want to assign serial no of each cities separately as image 2.

[image: Image 1]<--Result-->[image: Image 2]

Any suggestion or any link of similar answer will help me a lot.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In **B2** enter:

```
1
```

In **B3** enter:

```
=IF(A3=A2,B2+1,1)
```

and copy down